# action_mailer конфигурация в application классе, а не в файле окружения

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, config

rails документация по ActionMailer предлагает описывать конфигурации в файле окружения, например:

```
config/environments/development.rb

Rails.application.configure do
 ...
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets.email_settings[:smtp_settings]
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => localhost:3000 }
  ...
end
```

и всё хорошо.

Я пытаюсь найти способ описать эти конфиги в ApplicationMailer, что то вроде:

```
mailers/application_mailer.rb

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: Rails.application.secrets.email_settings[:from]

  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets.email_settings[:smtp_settings]
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }

end
```

и всё тоже вроде хорошо, до конца не уверен.

Есть ли более элегантные способы описать конфигурации для action mailer вне файла окружения, и может ли это вызвать какие-то проблемы?

Comment: А чем вам не удобен дефолтный вариант? Проблема будет одна - одинаковый конфиг для всех окружений. Зачем вам настройки продакшна в тестовом и дев окружениях?

Comment: Проблему с окружениями можно решить переменными окружения. Дефолтный вариант не единственный получается, пытаюсь узнать другие подходы